# Oracle SQL - change decimal dot for a comma

Tags: oracle, currency, number-formatting

I'm on Brazil, and our currency format is something like 'R$ 9.999,00'.

I'm trying to select a field, and change the format of the return. However, it seems I can't do it. I've tried:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

and

```
SELECT to_char(10,'9,999.00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL
```

None of those worked. Not sure if it might be my client (I'm on Ubuntu using sqldeveloper), or if I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT to_char(10,'9G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL
```

G is symbol for thousands separator
D is for decimal separator

Comment: :If the number increases to 8 digit then how will this be cater?

Answer (score 4):

I think that your format mask is wrong.Please try this format mask:

```
SELECT to_char(10000,'99G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL
```

make sure you will use correct number of leading '9' in format mask for bigger numbers

Comment: This works if even result is zero. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1000000000,'999G999G999G999D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;
```

to format a number by billions. I think it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION APPS.EX_number_format( ff number) RETURN char IS

xx varchar2(100);
yy varchar2(1);
tt varchar2(100);
x number:=0;
begin
xx:=to_char(ff,'99G990G990G990G990G990D00');
for i  in 1..length(xx) loop
yy:=substr(xx,i,1);
if yy in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') then
x:=i;
exit;
end if;
end loop;

tt:=substr(xx,x,length(xx));
return tt;

END EX_number_format;
```

select EX_number_format(1000) from dual;

1,000.00

select EX_number_format(1859684500) from dual;

1,859,684,500.00

Comment: Just go through [How to Answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) , instead of directly writing SQLs as answer.